# Python Pandas pivot table how to handle '\xc2\xa0'?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, encoding

I have a sample dataset  as follows:

[image: Sample Input]

So I want to have the time series set, and hence all the time series as the column headers. So my script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
import os
from os.path import basename


def generate_timeSeries(fileToProcess):

    df = pd.read_csv(fileToProcess)
    timestamps = df.pivot_table('C_Number',['A_Id', 'P_Id'], 'Time Stamp')

    return timestamps

def main():

    folder_path = "Input/"

    for files in os.listdir(folder_path):

        print "processing",files
        file_to_open = os.path.join(folder_path, files)
        unicoded_file = unicode(file_to_open).encode('utf8')
        TimeSeries_dataframe = generate_timeSeries(unicoded_file)


        TimeSeries_dataframe.to_csv('Output/%s_timeseries.csv' % os.path.splitext(files)[0], sep=',', encoding='utf-8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I try to run the script, I get the following error:

```
pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Here is the complete error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Error_AuthorTimeSeries.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "Error_AuthorTimeSeries.py", line 33, in main
    TimeSeries_dataframe = generate_timeSeries(unicoded_file)
  File "Error_AuthorTimeSeries.py", line 16, in generate_timeSeries
    timestamps = df.pivot_table('C_Number',['A_ID', 'P_ID'], 'Time Stamp')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.py", line 104, in pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 437, in agg
    return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1994, in aggregate
    return getattr(self, arg)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 452, in mean
    return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1917, in _cython_agg_general
    new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1964, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

**P.S**: Near duplicates to this question are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802961/pivot-table-problems-error-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802961/pivot-table-problems-error-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564959/simple-pandas-pivot-table-issue). However, they did not provide satisfactory answer to my problem.

I tried with `fill_value` and `astype` methods. No luck with them.

**Edit**:
I tried to find what is causing the errors by adding following (based on the suggestions

```
pd.unique(df['C_number'].values)
```

and got the following result:

```
['163' '143' '51' '43' '34' '24' '20' '15' '14' '12' '11' '10' '9' '8' '7'
 '6' '5' '4' '3' '2' '1' '\xc2\xa0' '145' '35' '16' '164' '146' '36' '21'
 '165' '148' '37' '171' '154' '52' '44' '22' '17' '13' '158' '160' '147'
 '161']
```

So I believe that **'\xc2\xa0'** is the culprit, inspite of repeatedly using encoding in UTF-8. So I added the following two lines to the function `generate_timeSeries()`:

```
df.loc[df['Cited By Numbers']=='\xc2\xa0', 'Cited By Numbers' ] = '0'
df['Cited By Numbers'] = df['Cited By Numbers'].astype(int)
```

Though it seems to be a temporary solution for files having `'\xc2\xa0'`, it seems to be a problem for files which **DOES NOT** have those characters as it lead to the following error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imeSeries.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "TimeSeries.py", line 56, in main
    TimeSeries_dataframe = generate_timeSeries(unicoded_file)
  File "TimeSeries.py", line 23, in generate_timeSeries
    df.loc[df['C_Numbers']=='\xc2\xa0', 'C_Numbers' ] = '0'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 563, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 532, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

**What is the correct way to resolve this issue?**

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show some lines of your input csv. Seems it's recognized as text.

Comment: Oh I see, you've got some glyphs in that column. Replace those by empty values maybe (before importing to pandas)?

Comment: @MKesper How do I replace? I don't know what cahracters they are. When I open in text editors like `gedit`, they appear as blank spaces.

Comment: could you try something like a dataframe.fillna(0)?

Comment: @Sword Tried it. Did not help. The same error.

Comment: if it is a blank space, you could also check with df['C_number'] = df['C_number'].replace(to_replace = r'\s+', value = '0', regex=True)  followed by a astype('int') or 'float' conversion..?

Comment: @Sword The error continues :(

Comment: pd.unique(df['C_number'].values) . What does it display?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95914/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-sword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort this issue by adding the following line to the original script.

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```